# Number of representations of a given dimension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a (semi)simple algebraic group over $\mathbb C$ and let $d \in \mathbb Z_{>0}$ a fixed integer.

> Let us suppose that there is an irreducible $G$-representation $V$ such that $\dim V=d$. Can we count in general how many more irreducible $G$-representations of dimension $d$ there are?

For sure, given $V$, there is also its dual $V^\vee$. In which case is there something else? I mean, like in the case if triality where $G=Spin_8(\mathbb C)$ where there are three irreducible representations $V(\omega_1),V(\omega_3),V(\omega_4)$ of dimension $d=8$.

**Edit 1:** I have tried to use the Weyl dimension formula. Let us suppose that we have two irreducible $G$-representations $V,V'$ given by highest weights
$$
\lambda=\sum_i m_i \omega_i \quad \text{and} \quad \mu=\sum_i p_i \omega_i
$$
where $m_i, p_i \in \mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$ and $\omega_1,\ldots, \omega_n$ is a base of fundamental weights.
If $\dim V= \dim V'$ it must hold that
$$
\prod_{\alpha \in \Phi^+}\left( \sum_i (m_i +1)\langle \omega_i,\alpha \rangle \right)=\prod_{\alpha \in \Phi^+}\left( \sum_i (p_i +1)\langle \omega_i,\alpha \rangle \right)
$$
where $\Phi^+$ denotes the set of positive roots of the root system associated to the Lie algebra of $G$. At this point, the only information I have is that
$$
m_i+1 \ge 1 \quad \text{and} \quad p_i+1 \ge 1
$$
but I don't understand if this way leads me to somewhere.

Comment: Does the Weyl dimension formula help?

Comment: Depending on exactly what you mean by "can we count," yes, as @ArB says the Weyl dimension formula should allow you to do this. For instance, unless I'm very confused it should tell you that the dimension of the representation with highest weight $m_1\omega_1 + m_2\omega_2 +\cdots + m_r\omega_r$ is given by a polynomial in $m_1,\ldots,m_r$. So then you want to see if there is a positive integral solution to that polynomial equaling $d$. Of course, in light of Hilbert's 10th problem, that might not actually be decidable...

Comment: @SamHopkins This is surely decidable for a given $G$, since you only need to evaluate it on the Weyl chamber, where the polynomial increases rapidly as you move away from the vertex in every dimension.

Comment: @WillSawin: good point! In fact the polynomial should have positive coefficients in the $m_1,\ldots,m_r$ (which is basically what you said).